# How to properly use ftruncate(int aux, off_set n) in c++

Tags: posix, shared-memory, ubuntu-18.04

Hello Im trying to add a shared memory space with a function, I am doing it like this:

```
void CreateSpace(int size, std::string name){

int aux;
int aux2;


aux = shm_open(name.c_str(),  O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if(aux > 0){
    aux2 = ftruncate(aux, sizeof(int)*2);
    if( aux2 != -1){

        works

    }else{

        It does not work
    }
}else{
Shared Memory Already Created }
```

The problem is that I am always getting the part that does not work, I delete manually the shared spaces in dev/shm but when I try to create a new one space that does no exists and try to set a specific size I am always getting ftruncate = -1. How can I solve this?  I tried to use size insted of sizeof(int)*2 but I get the same results.

When I try to use it y just call it like:

```
CreateSpace(5, "/test1");
```

It does create the space /test1 but I get error when I try to set a specific Size with ftruncate(int aux, off_set n) and always getting errno 22.

Comment: I resolve my problem by using shm_open(name.c_str(),  O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,S_IRWXU ). I am still trying to figure out why the other code is giving me problems.